# Vacuum loop in $\phi^4$ scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, scattering, feynman-diagrams

$\newcommand{\Ket}[1]{\left|#1\right>}$
$\newcommand{\Bra}[1]{\left<#1 \right| }$

I am studying QFT through Peskin & Schroeder's book and currently I am doing the part of scattering in $\phi^4$ theory. On Page 113 (Eq. 4.102) it is written the following expression for the amplitude calculated of the Feynman diagram attached

[image]

\begin{equation}
   = \frac{1}{2} \int \frac{d^4 p'}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{p'^2 - m^2} \int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{k^2 - m^2} \times (-i \lambda) (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (p_A + p' - p_1 - p_2) \times (-i \lambda) (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (p_B - p').\tag{4.102}
\end{equation}

It is affirmed that there is an infinity in the calculation involving $p'$ because the second delta function makes $p' \rightarrow p_B$ and $p_B$ is on-shell, so there appears a 1/0. That is clear to me, however it is not clear how the book gets this result. For the loop leg, I tried

\begin{equation}
 \Bra{\mathbf{p'}} (\frac{-i \lambda}{4!} N \{ \int d^4 x \overline{\phi(x)\phi(x)} \phi(x)\phi(x) \}) \Ket{\mathbf{p}_B} = 2 (\frac{-i \lambda}{4!}) \int d^4 x D_F (x-x) e^{ip' \cdot x} e^{-i p_B \cdot x}.
\end{equation}

My motivation for this expression is having only one particle in the initial and final state and the contraction (represented by the overline) representing the loop. For the scattering with the four legs, I used:

\begin{align*}
    \Bra{\mathbf{p_1 p_2}} (\frac{-i \lambda}{4!}) N\{ \int d^4 z \phi(z)\phi(z)\phi(z)\phi(z) \} \Ket{\mathbf{p_A p'}} &= \frac{-i \lambda}{4!} \int d^4 z \exp{[-i(p_A + p' - p_1 - p_2) \cdot z]}\\
 &= \frac{-i \lambda}{4!} (2\pi)^4 \delta^{(4)} (p_A + p' - p_1 - p_2)
\end{align*}

which so far makes total sense to me (apart from the prefactors from combinatorics). The point is that the result in the book shows an additional propagator involving $p'$, as you can check. How do I get this extra term? What should I do, in general, to solve this kind of diagram?

Comment: Though it's a bit belated... combine your results! Put in another propagator going from $x$ to $z$, and multiply all three terms together. The result will have integrals that let you simplify those remaining exponentials and delta fuctions.